# Visual Studio debug web app from another machine in the same network

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, xamarin

I wrote a web-app  asp.net (.net framework) identity framework in Visual studio 2019, for different reasons I used a Windows PC to do it.

The consumer of this web app is a mobile application, I wrote it in xamarin forms but in iOS pc (another machine in the same network).

When I run the web app I use postman to check if my controllers works fine by sending request to `https://localhost:1234'` (random port).

Obviusly from Mac I can't use the localhost path, for this reason I do these steps:

1. In `Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config` file I addthe string  `<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:8080:" />` (I tried also with`<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:8080:*" />`)
2. from command line i run `netsh http add urlacl url=http://*:1234/ user=Everyone`
3. I retrieve the IP from `ipconfig /all`
4. I run visual studio as Admin

but when I try to send the request it return the `Could not get any response` error.

I tried also with `htpps://COMPUTER-NAME:1234/` but the result is the same.

So, my question is, how I can debug the web app run locally on windows machine from another machine in the same network?

Thank you

G.

Comment: there are many, many existing questions that explain how to access IIS Express from remote clients.  https://www.google.com/search?q=iisexpress+remote+requests+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: Hi , if want to another machine to visit the web app , have a try with `htpps://COMPUTER-IP-ADRESS:1234/` instead of `htpps://COMPUTER-NAME:1234/` .